# Error showing product on homepage in Magento 1.9.0.1

Tags: php, magento, categories

I am using Magento 1.9.0.1
What I would like to do is to show a specific category on homepage.
For example I have created a product category "LATEST" in manage categories.

I have tried below code I picked up from a forum but it has given error on homepage:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_new" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_homepage" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

ERROR:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getSortedChildren() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\magento1901\app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\catalog\product\list.phtml on line 134
```

Could you please advise how can I add this category to homepage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look @ [Show products on homepage magento 1.9](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/20984/show-products-on-homepage-magento-1-9)

You will also need to add the `category_id` for `LATEST`

> {{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_homepage" category_id="4" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}